# Convert comment in element

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to convert a text delimited by comments in a element which contains this text.

Source XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DOC>
<TEXT>
<!--SectionLeRubrum-->
<para>R1</para>
<para>R2</para>
<para>...</para>
<!--SectionFaits-->
<para>F1</para>
<para>F2</para>
<para>...</para>
<!--SectionConsiderants-->
<para>C1</para>
<para>C2</para>
<para>...</para>
<!--SectionDispositif-->
<para>D1</para>
<para>D2</para>
<para>...</para>
</TEXT>
</DOC>
```

Which I need to convert to :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DOC>
<TEXT>
<!--SectionLeRubrum-->
<p>R1</p>
<p>R2</p>
<p>...</p>
<!--SectionFaits-->
<p>F1</p>
<p>F2</p>
<p>...</p>
<!--SectionConsiderants-->
<zone type="considerants">
    <p>C1</p>
    <p>C2</p>
    <p>...</p>
</zone>
<!--SectionDispositif-->
<p>D1</p>
<p>D2</p>
<p>...</p>
</TEXT>
</DOC>
```

I've tried to used following instructions, but I'm unable to remove "C1", "C2" paragraphs repeated after I put the "zone" element.

```
<xsl:template match="comment()[contains(.,'SectionConsiderants')]">
    <zone type="considerants">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[preceding-sibling::comment()[.='SectionConsiderants'] and following-sibling::comment()[.='SectionDispositif']][node()]" mode="Zone" />
    </zone>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment()">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[preceding-sibling::comment()[.='SectionConsiderants'] and following-sibling::comment()[.='SectionDispositif']]" mode="Zone">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

False output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DOC>
<TEXT>
<!--SectionLeRubrum-->
<p>R1</p>
<p>R2</p>
<p>...</p>
<!--SectionFaits-->
<p>F1</p>
<p>F2</p>
<p>...</p>
<!--SectionConsiderants-->
<zone type="considerants">
    <p>C1</p>
    <p>C2</p>
    <p>...</p>
</zone>
<p>C1</p>
<p>C2</p>
<p>...</p>
<!--SectionDispositif-->
<p>D1</p>
<p>D2</p>
<p>...</p>
</TEXT>
</DOC>
```

If I use a complementary rule such as :

```
<xsl:template match="*[preceding-sibling::comment()='SectionConsiderants' and following-sibling::comment()='SectionDispositif']" />
```

It will give the following false result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DOC>
<TEXT>
<!--SectionLeRubrum-->
<p>R1</p>
<p>R2</p>
<p>...</p>
<!--SectionFaits-->
<p>F1</p>
<p>F2</p>
<p>...</p>
<!--SectionConsiderants-->
<zone type="considerants" />
<!--SectionDispositif-->
<p>D1</p>
<p>D2</p>
<p>...</p>
</TEXT>
</DOC>
```

Using the "grouping" proposed solution with "key" resolved the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to "capture" the `<p>` you don't want to output in a template with no mode. Can you us how you process the `<p>` elements in your stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly standard *grouping problem* - you need to associate each `para` element with its nearest preceding comment, then process the *comments* and do the appropriate thing with each group.  You can use a *key* to achieve this:

```
<xsl:key name="paraByComment" match="para"
         use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::comment()[1])" />

<xsl:template match="TEXT">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="comment()" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment()[. = 'SectionConsiderants']">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <zone type="considerants">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('paraByComment', generate-id())" />
  </zone>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment()">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('paraByComment', generate-id())" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para">
  <p><!-- do whatever you need with the para content --></p>
</xsl:template>
```

The key allows you to retrieve, for a given comment, all the `para` elements that come between this comment and the next one (or this comment and the end of the `TEXT`, if it's the last comment).

Answer (score 0):

in principle, you have to exclude these elements in "normal" mode by a template like this:

```
 <xsl:template match="*[preceding-sibling::comment()='SectionConsiderants' and following-sibling::comment()='SectionDispositif']"/>
```

However, this all just works once: If you happen to have more than one "zone", then the result is probably not what you want.